# Problem in querying firebase recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Iam new to android development ,Currently i'am facing with the issue is what while querying firebase recyclerView adapter for sorting dates ,everything works fine in that page, but when clicks on the particular event and goes to the next page some data's is missing or malfunctioning, look at the code below,

```
EventsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    String eventId = ds.child("eid").getValue(String.class);
                    String serveCount = ds.child("serve").getValue(String.class);

                    list.add(eventId);
                    list3.add(serveCount);

                }

                if (list.size() != 0)
                {
                   RecyclerView();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
                txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


private void RecyclerView()
{
    DatabaseReference MyEventsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query ref = MyEventsRef.child("Workers Details").child(userID).child("My Events").orderByChild("sort_Date");

    //Display events
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<WorkerMyEvents> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<WorkerMyEvents>()
                    .setQuery(ref, WorkerMyEvents.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WorkerMyEvents, WorkerMyEventViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WorkerMyEvents, WorkerMyEventViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final WorkerMyEventViewHolder eventsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final WorkerMyEvents newEvents)
        {
            //Id with date and time key
            final String IDs = getRef(i).getKey();
            final String eventIDs = IDs.substring(0,18);

            final String serve = list3.get(i);

            NewEventsRef.child(eventIDs).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        final String serveCount = serve;
                        final String Eid = dataSnapshot.child("Eid").getValue().toString();
                        final String FromDate = dataSnapshot.child("Total Service Dates").child("From").getValue().toString();
                        final String ToDate = dataSnapshot.child("Total Service Dates").child("To").getValue().toString();

                        eventsViewHolder.eventType.setText(event);
                        eventsViewHolder.totalAmount.setText(FromDate + " - " + ToDate);
                        eventsViewHolder.ServeCount.setText(serveCount);

                        eventsViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(WorkerMyEventActivity.this, WorkerMyEventDetailsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("Eid", Eid);
                                intent.putExtra("sC", serve);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                        eventsViewHolder.opt_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                DeletingEvent(IDs, Eid, serve);
                            }
                        });

                        eventsViewHolder.cash_received.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        //notify to the participants...
                        //random key
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMYYYY");
                        Date date = new Date();
                        String tdyDate = formatter.format(date);

                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmma");
                        String saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());

                        String randomkey = tdyDate + saveCurrentTime;
                        //random key


                        String Notify = "The event you participated has been deleted by contractor";
                        HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("message", eventIDs + " - " + Notify);
                        workerRef.child("Notifications").child(randomkey).updateChildren(map);
                        workerRef.child("Notifications").child("current_counts").child(randomkey).updateChildren(map);

                        //remove Live event event id's from database...
                        EventsRef.child(eventIDs).removeValue();
                        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public WorkerMyEventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.worker_my_event_layout, parent, false);
            WorkerMyEventViewHolder holder = new WorkerMyEventViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

this is my code all works fine in current activity. But while doing this [ Query ref = EventsRef.orderByChild("Sort_Date"); ] some data's or reference problem is coming in the next page .

NextActivity(); //code where iam facing issue

```
ref3Male = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("New Events")
            .child(EventId).child("Live Event Details").child("Live counts")
            .child("Male").child(serveCount).child("Ids and Details");ref3Male.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
        {
            //This needs to come ,if that query is not applied in the previous activity this works fine. but while using that it is not working, its movingto else part.
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

In the above code actually the dataSnapShot will exists if the query is not applied in previous activity, but while using that it going to else part, Please guide me where i'm doing mistake friends. Thanks in advance.

Model class

```
public class WorkerMyEvents
{
private long sort_Date;

public WorkerMyEvents() {
}

public WorkerMyEvents(long sort_Date) {
    this.sort_Date = sort_Date;
}

public long getSort_Date() {
    return sort_Date;
}

public void setSort_Date(long sort_Date) {
    this.sort_Date = sort_Date;
}
```

}

[image]

By using the above database structure i will get key by sorting dates and by using the key i will get details from the node which that database structure is below ,( i posted only one node structure but it will have many)

[image]

That second image reference is what iam using in next activity()..

And also now i have noticed and changed that date type from string to long type using timestamp , but still having that issue ...

And also i researched something and noticed that in activity 1 there will have list of items in recycler view , in that only 1st and 2nd event is only having that issue and remaining is working perfectly , by when i clicks that event those details viewing in next page.

Now i noticed another thing was in the activity 1 ,for 1st two items the reference is not working (ref - is in the 1st image) and the remaining is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**I would say that you shouldn't read the data first and then set the `onClickListener` in your `onBindViewHolder()`**

**First you set the `onClickListener` to the item, then onClick of the item you read the data and pass them:**

Instead of doing this:

```
        NewEventsRef.child(eventIDs).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    final String serveCount = serve;
                    final String Eid = dataSnapshot.child("Eid").getValue().toString();
                    final String FromDate = dataSnapshot.child("Total Service Dates").child("From").getValue().toString();
                    final String ToDate = dataSnapshot.child("Total Service Dates").child("To").getValue().toString();

                    eventsViewHolder.eventType.setText(event);
                    eventsViewHolder.totalAmount.setText(FromDate + " - " + ToDate);
                    eventsViewHolder.ServeCount.setText(serveCount);

                    eventsViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(WorkerMyEventActivity.this, WorkerMyEventDetailsActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("Eid", Eid);
                            intent.putExtra("sC", serve);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

       ....................
       ....................
```

Do this:

```
 ........
 ........

//Id with date and time key
final String IDs = getRef(i).getKey();
final String eventIDs = IDs.substring(0,18);
final String serve = list3.get(i);

//now you set the onClickListener:

eventsViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

//here you read the data that you need to pass


NewEventsRef.child(eventIDs).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

//get the data
progressDialog.dismiss();

final String serveCount = serve;
final String Eid = dataSnapshot.child("Eid").getValue().toString();
final String FromDate = dataSnapshot.child("Total Service Dates").child("From").getValue().toString();
final String ToDate = dataSnapshot.child("Total Service Dates").child("To").getValue().toString();

eventsViewHolder.eventType.setText(event);
eventsViewHolder.totalAmount.setText(FromDate + " - " + ToDate);
eventsViewHolder.ServeCount.setText(serveCount);

//pass the data and open new activity
Intent intent = new Intent(WorkerMyEventActivity.this, WorkerMyEventDetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Eid", Eid);
intent.putExtra("sC", serve);
startActivity(intent);

}else{
.....................
.....................
}

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
progressDialog.dismiss();
}


});


}
}); //end of the click listener of the item

 ..................
 .................
```

Comment: If this i applied means only when i clicks the item it will display the item details or content in that, and once again if i clicked it will go to next page, but now it will show details. Instead of that i got some ideas , i used that onclick listner outside the singleValueEventListener( ) , which i already used inside the singleValueEventListener( ) and  now its working perfectly.. Anyway i got these idea because of you , thanks a lot bro.